# Complex accounting calculations from a slow temporary table

Tags: php, mysql

I have been tasked to write a complicated invoicing and billing system with reports. The structure of the database is such that returning the invoices' totals and figures requires a complicated string of joins and calculations that is cumbersome to troubleshoot and highly sensitive to error.

Rather than produce a library of long and complicated queries throughout my reporting system, I opted to use a temporary table that will perform the necessary calculations and hold the figures next to a record ID number that I can join into when and where needed. This made coding the system much easier, but it also made the database noticeably slower as every page hit that needs to use this temp table must populate it first.

In summary, I've got a reporting system that must be able to display calculated figures from a series of several invoice tables. Can anyone offer advice on an approach or solution that would simplify this process without costing me server speed?

Comment: Code Slowness might be caused by the queries you have used. They each have an impact on the server, we usually talk micrososeconds; but these can add up. post a chunk of your code for reference

Comment: I considered that already. If I comment out the process that generates this table, I get normal page generation speed every time. If I call on my temp table, an additional 4 to 6 seconds are added to the page load, generating roughly 7,000 calculated records. It's not slow code.

I will add some code if I need help troubleshooting some. Right now, I'm asking for a better approach.

Comment: I would hope you have an obvious index to match the join criteria... just asking...

Comment: Yes, I've checked the indexing carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to judge as your description is too generic.

One of the possible solutions: If the reports you are generating allow to be a little outdated, then you could create a regular table instead of a temporary one and populate it with all the info using an *event scheduler* as often as needed (e.g. once a day or once an hour).

Comment: Too generic? I'm not sure how much more clear I can make it. I am generating reports using calculated fields. The process to get those calculations is too cumbersome to be done in a thousand places. Instead, I do it one place, but having to populate 7,000+ records per page hit too slow. What is the better way? That is the question. I considered writing a cron that would do what you're describing and may resort to that if a better option isn't there.